# concatenate print stmt inside and outside of for loop into a sentence in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def PrintFruiteListSentence(list_of_fruits):
print 'You would like to eat',
    for i, item in enumerate (list_of_fruits):
        if i != (len(list_of_fruits) - 1):
            print item, 'as fruit', i+2, 'and',
        else:
            print item, 'as fruit', i+2,
    print 'in your diet'
```

o/p 
You would like to eat apple as fruit 1 and orange as fruit 2 and banana as fruit 3 and grape as fruit 4 in your diet.

How can i get this sentence in a variable which i can pass to another function ???
I want to pass this sentence as input to another function.

Comment: look up string concatenation in python. create a variable and concatenate each piece to that variable. then send that variable to the other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your call to `print` instead to a concatenation into an actual string.

```
def PrintFruiteListSentence(list_of_fruits):
    sentence = 'You would like to eat '
    for i, item in enumerate (list_of_fruits):
        if i != (len(list_of_fruits) - 1):
            sentence += item + ' as fruit ' + str(i+2) + ' and '
        else:
            sentence += item + ' as fruit ' + str(i+2)
    sentence += ' in your diet'
    print sentence
```

you could also use a list comprehension instead of a for loop but this is just unnecessary:

Also note that if you want `i` to start at a specific number, you can pass an index into `enumerate`

```
>>> def PrintFruiteListSentence(list_of_fruits):
        sentence = 'You would like to eat ' + ' and '.join(fruit + ' as fruit ' + str(index) for index,fruit in enumerate(list_of_fruits,1)) + ' in your diet'
        print(sentence)


>>> PrintFruiteListSentence(['apple','orange','grapes'])
You would like to eat apple as fruit 1 and orange as fruit 2 and grapes as fruit 3 in your diet
```

EDIT: make sure to convert `i+2` to `str(i+2)`

Comment: i am trying to use the solution you suggested in above..but getting the following error
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: check the edit, i saw the error before i realized i didnt update my code

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make it a variable, like so:

```
def PrintFruiteListSentence(list_of_fruits):
    myStr = 'You would like to eat ',
    for i, item in enumerate (list_of_fruits):
        if i != (len(list_of_fruits) - 1):
            myStr += item + ' as fruit ' + str(i+2)+ ' and '
        else:
            myStr += item + ' as fruit ' + str(i+2)
    myStr +=  ' in your diet'
    return myStr
def otherFunction(inputString):
    print(inputString)

otherFunction(PrintFruiteListSentence(['apple','banana']))#example
```

Also look at `str.format()`, which makes life much easier.

EDIT:

Here is an example to illustrate a simple usage of `str.format()`. It might not seem powerful in this case, but can be very helpful for complicated string manipulation, or where you need a specific floating point format.

```
def formatExample(list_of_fruits):
    myStr="you would like to eat "
    for i in enumerate(list_of_fruits,1):
        myStr += '{1:} as fruit {0:d}'.format(*i)+' and '
    return myStr[:-4]+"in your diet."

otherFunction(formatExample(['apple','banana']))#prints the same thing
```

Comment: Use str.format in the example if you believe it makes life easier instead of mentioning it after your solution.

Comment: @dopstar Added an example

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
def func(fruits):
    start = "You would like to eat "
    for i, item in enumerate(fruits):
        if i != (len(fruits) - 1):
            start += item + ' as fruit ' + str(i+1) + ' and '    # note you mistake(i+1 and not i+2)
        else:
            start += item + ' as fruit ' + str(i+1)     # see above comment note

    start += ' in your diet'
    return start

print (func(["apple", "banana", "grapes"]))
```

You can also try to run the above snippet [here on repl.it](https://repl.it/B1W4)

Answer (score 0):

Okay this question has been answered already. But here is another take where the `str.join` method takes the center stage it deserves. No concatenating strings with `+`. No `if / else` statements. No unnecessary variables. Easy to read and understand whats happening:

```
def PrintFruiteListSentence(fruits):
    return ' '.join([
        'You would like to eat',
        ' and '.join(
            '{0} as fruit {1}'.format(f, c) for c, f in enumerate(fruits, 1)
        ),
        'in your diet'
    ])
```